# Rails 'order' for association (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to order books by library like so: `books.includes(:library).order("libraries.name")`, but got such error: `ERROR -- : Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'libraries.name' in 'order clause'...`

book.rb:

```
belongs_to :library, class_name: "Bibliotheca", foreign_key: :bibliotheca_id
```

bibliotheca.rb

```
has_many :books, class_name: "Book", foreign_key: :bibliotheca_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you need to change the table name in your `order` to

`order('bibliothecas.name')`

When you pass a string or hash argument to AR queries you need the actual table names and not the AR alias.